# Doctrine ORM to Elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, doctrine-orm, foselasticabundle

Hello guys I am banging my head with this thing at the moment. I am trying to convert it to elastic search query like

```
    $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();
    $fieldQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
    $fieldQuery->setFieldQuery('title', 'searchTern');
    $boolQuery->addShould($fieldQuery);
```

..
but my struggle is in vain so far :(. I am quite new to elasticsearch so forgive me if it`s a simple question but I was unable to find understandable (to me) join equivalent. Thanks in advance.

This is my Doctrine ORM query:

```
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('article')
                    ->addSelect('aTrans')
                    ->join('article.translations', 'aTrans')
                    ->join('NameSpace\Entity\Article', 'front',
                               'WITH', 'front.article = article')
                    ->andWhere('aTrans.locale = :locale')
                    ->setParameter("locale", $locale)
                    ->andWhere('article.isActive = true')
                    ->orderBy('article.createdAt', 'DESC')
                    ->setMaxResults($limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch you don't really do joins. Elasticsearch gets its speed from working with denormalized data. It basically means that you have all the data you need in the index. Check out elasticsearch documentation about that [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html).

You should also read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) documentation by elasticsearch.